# MacOS: How can I unlock a system plist file to edit? [trying to get rid of a stray Netskope VPN entry]

Tags: macos, permission, vpn, plist, administrator

I'm trying to get rid of a stray Netskope Client (NSClient1) VPN entry that wouldn't go away. I found its traces only in /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist - this is the system's plist not my users. I'm the only user on the system and have admin privileges.

However the file is locked and despite being an admin, I can't edit it. Can someone please help me figure out how do I edit this file (or remove the stray VPN entry)?

Steps taken so far: (all result in operation not permitted or I don't have permissions to change)

- tried to change permissions (via finder's get info option as well as
  chmod through the terminal)
- tried to copy the file to the desktop,
  edit it and then replace
- contacted Apple support (and they said it's
  not their problem - quite literally)
- contacted Netskope (VPN support)
  and tried to run their uninstaller but that didn't work either

[the VPN entry doesn't get listed when I run sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices]

I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the nouchg or noschg flag set? If so, remove it by following the instructions in the chflags(1) man page.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, the chflags execute in terminal but the file remains locked.

Comment: remains uneditable*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the SIP (system integrity protection) on macOS was blocking changes to system plists. I had to disable that to make any edits.

To disable, boot in recovery mode and enter `csrutil disable` through the terminal; then reboot.

Once done, you can run `csrutil enable` to enable it again and `csrutil status` to check its status.

> PS: Not recommended to do this if you don't know what this all means. Always backup.